# Implement paypal payment in app Android

Tags: android, paypal, sdk, payment

I would like to implement payment via paypal.
I downloaded the example samplepaypalsdk and I tye to modify:
NFIG_CLIENT_ID
CONFIG_RECEIVER_EMAIL
with the data generated from the center of development.

In addition I have also modified
EXTRA_CLIENT_ID, "buyer@paypalsandbox.com"
EXTRA_PAYER_ID, "mypayer"

I run the app and I bought the jeans, now I would see the status of transaction?
I tried to search in developer center, but I didn't find it. I would understand how can I manage a transaction...

Answer (score 0):

There is currently a problem displaying AdaptivePayment transactions in the developer console. (AdaptivePayments is the name of the "classic" API that is used by the Mobile SDKs to process PayPal transactions).

However, you can see the notification generated by this transaction in the notifications section, and you can log in to the sandbox webapp as either buyer or seller to see the transaction record.